# How to build a regular expression to get some lines?

Tags: regex, bash

I am dealing with a text that looks as follows:

```
FAPK   FAPK891  FACEBOOK       *BIPARY R       P
FAPK   FAPK891  FACEBOOK       *BIPARY S       P
.
.
.
FAOO   FAOO891  FACEBOOK       *BIPARY R       P
FAOO   FAOO891  FACEBOOK       *BIPARY S       P
```

The fact is that I want to obtain just the lines that have the following pattern:

```
*BIPARY R
```

The thing is that, that pattern can be in some place line per line, that is not fixed, I tried with:

```
grep "BIPARY"
```

but it gave me all the lines, also I tried with:

```
grep -e '.*\*BIPARY R.*$' text
```

but it does not give nothing,
I would like to appreciate any suggestion to overcome this situation, I am having problems with the "*" symbol and with the space, and since that pattern could appear in some place of the lines that I want I believe that the best approach is to build a regular expression, thanks any how.

My desired output would be just the lines with that specific pattern I mean:

```
FAOO   FAOO891  FACEBOOK       *BIPARY R       P
```

Comment: Your second command works for me. What do you mean with "does not give nothing"? You don't get any matches?

Comment: `grep -w 'BIPARY R' text` - why do you need regular expression?

Comment: thanks for the support, what would be the meaning of "w", I know that this seems really strange but when I copy an paste from the terminal to my computer a small piece of the text, it works but when I try with the complete text in the original terminal It does not work, since I am working with data that contains private information I am not able to show the text,   I am just sure about that I need a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep ".*\*BIPARY\sR.*" text

Wherever there are special character and if that is expected to be in the text escape those with backslash.
```

space represented as  **\s**

Comment: thanks I appreciate the support, I was looking for a regular expression, since I need to proceed ensuring the result.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the pattern is a fixed string "*BIPARY R" - you'll get much faster performance with grep -F - also a leading and trailing .* don't buy you anything in a grep regex

```
grep -F '*BIPARY R'
```